# No-Index robots meta tag in an iframe's effect on page

Tags: iframe, seo, google-search

I am working on a website who's pages were deindexed en mass by Google roughly 2 months ago. This coincided with a bunch of hard 404s and the implementation of a few features, namely the presence of an iframe which has a noindex robot meta tag. I was wondering if this would have any impact on the website it is embedded in or not.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
  ...
  <iframe>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
      ...
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice / behaviour of search engine services. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are *not* search engine friendly. That alone can be responsible for your problems. Addtionally, you are explicitly telling search engines not to index your content by using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`. So even if they did crawl framed content they wouldn't index it anyway. It's a double whammy.

Comment: Just to clarify, the iframe is only a small portion of the website and doesn't contain the entirety of its content. Would even a "comments" iframe have a major impact on the page's indexing? And would the robots tag *inside* the iframe affect the content *outside* the iframe?

Comment: An iframe shouldn't have a negative effect on a page of it contains just a small amount of content and is not the main page content. And the robots tag on the iframe shouldn't affect the page the iframe is embedded in.